# amCharts: dynamically changing bullet color

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm using AmChart for making a line chart. I want to dynamically change the color of the bullet (bulletColor) according to the y-values. So for example:

Default bulletcolor: green
With a value above 103% the color of the bullet should be orange
With a value above 105% the color of the bullet should be red.

I noticed there are customfields that take data from the json for 'bulletSizeField' and 'bulletField'(custom bulletpicture) but I can't find if the same is possible for changing only the color of the bullet. 
Does anybody know if there's a way to accomplish this result? (either in AmChart itself or get the colordata from the jsonfile like with 'BulletField').

Answer (score 1):

You could, within your script that generates the dataProvider data, add some logic and pass the colour each time based on the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/qkc8bgtq/

```
"dataProvider": [
  {
    "lineColor": "#00aa00",
    "date": "2012-01-01",
    "duration": 100
  },
  {
    "lineColor": "#00aa00",
    "date": "2012-01-02",
    "duration": 102
  },
  {
    "lineColor": "#ff9900",
    "date": "2012-01-03",
    "duration": 104
  },
  {
    "lineColor": "#aa0000",
    "date": "2012-01-04",
    "duration": 106
  },
  {
    "lineColor": "#aa0000",
    "date": "2012-01-05",
    "duration": 108
  }
]
```

Comment: but can you also pass bulletColor? I tried to but AmChart doesn't seem to take bordercolorvalues from the json. LineColor changes the bulletcolor but also changes the color of the line itself: I want the line to stay the same color throughout the chart and only make the bullet change color when reaching a certain value